# Google Place API not working for Android Key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using google autocomplete place api.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key="My Android Key"&input=Mg%20Ro&components=country:IN

the key i generated from console is Android-key

The API i enabled in Google API Console are

```
Google Places API Web Service
Google Places API for Android
Google Maps Android API
```

and SHA-1 finger print are of debug-keystore. 
Now on hitting, I'm getting the output for this link is

```
{"error_message":"This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address 122.177.199.201, with empty referer","predictions":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

While in case of Server-Key i'm getting proper response

```
{"predictions":[{"description":"MG Road Metro Station","id":"9db78081a8f0e59874d51baff0df2c007e8c8dde","matched_substrings":[{"length":2,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJY8G_aiIZDTkRohS7EKRePsw","reference":"CjQkAAAAj-nav4S-WWDQfmK7D5V_uc6XT8s5wZzsKNLQMHA7ucgRD_AGu5uIoxvWlxtpJaAiEhDOj61RTKbD9lK28Seovch6GhSPoMA7WPxS6v8ApRf_q03TtnzzrQ","terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"MG Road Metro Station"}],"types":["transit_station","point_of_interest","establishment","geocode"]},{"description":"M G Road Metro Station, Mehrauli-Gurgaon Road, Sector 28, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","id":"041408b314da313beac2e2016c697a9aba451be8","matched_substrings":[{"length":22,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJATH6EiIZDTkR-aEggPmaDrU","reference":"CmRgAAAAEMJLJnkGwPSnN5BmE7_IU_UTEAxRT83T2IuHGKja7PouwUxH6j6gVzPlWiSi-yPgYH1vEUs_wiLMME2QbSkOBACPdtQmPdjQ5q-BlLxL3d81UOvaD8-jtvgrKOLLF_dPEhCRDuiBXJ90DQMY7ioJsQxnGhSFULVBF754FuwF2LFwzWTvlxmVoQ","terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"M G Road Metro Station"},{"offset":24,"value":"Mehrauli-Gurgaon Road"},{"offset":47,"value":"Sector 28"},{"offset":58,"value":"Gurgaon"},{"offset":67,"value":"Haryana"},{"offset":76,"value":"India"}],"types":["transit_station","point_of_interest","establishment","geocode"]},{"description":"MGF MAll Management, DLF City Mall Parking Road, Sector 28, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","id":"c8e8961eb24684f8fa6457876e0f5c1d7c38b5b9","matched_substrings":[{"length":2,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJS3fMbyIZDTkRkexzrN-6sBg","reference":"CnRhAAAApKaoK6e148xwbkJZGhNXNTTDqStbf3vU5b0udThzC0jcdbtJceqWXcQ-I8U_x838GYjHTLLcNNswfrTu3jYVgnA-evtNfhN1pRKnugpvOAtonL2aEYmxGHQadW3bY8uzf-ERjosRBicEb2HfdoKZPhIQvUrFQqXv67CoiaWqlVqXUxoUBccSCK3csfVr1HA0H2HZOiqEmu8","terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"MGF MAll Management"},{"offset":21,"value":"DLF City Mall Parking Road"},{"offset":49,"value":"Sector 28"},{"offset":60,"value":"Gurgaon"},{"offset":69,"value":"Haryana"},{"offset":78,"value":"India"}],"types":["establishment"]},{"description":"MGF Infratech, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","id":"1b4b1ce2e29a7a8f3b3d07192bf06f7e6f0df84f","matched_substrings":[{"length":2,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJTytQ6hgZDTkR2p2nzYt9tfA","reference":"CkQ1AAAAgAsxqmineUN1diGhpF5khDroggPvicHj5VlegMg-SYKf3ORdoFU5JB9dp5lpRY5byp9LAIx3alsDZ0k4D5QCrxIQXi5gMF1JakSfbAufPMlvcRoUqMmrZiUzEmhdiVxMBneGKFLrmZg","terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"MGF Infratech"},{"offset":15,"value":"Gurgaon"},{"offset":24,"value":"Haryana"},{"offset":33,"value":"India"}],"types":["establishment"]},{"description":"MG Road, National Highway 236, Maruti Housing Colony, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","id":"20c271b151605328170192b769e72e3e9bee6056","matched_substrings":[{"length":2,"offset":0}],"place_id":"ChIJrYoVEyIZDTkRcmM4_rRo_OE","reference":"CmRcAAAAtEh471bANMlFV-mDp2hOSVxW0_XxmNFQEmGXCiuZxvjsLvOcoyMPC0VhOifD7ngb-2rs5cfplaomYupeARu3kKEf6WPBQ170Ge7ZRNscQ1PDx12EvHkm4R7MrUD2F_kZEhBq6yvt7WzJgAkdXholeEObGhTuXqJl41XcSz2dzzksTMsHsU7Nzg","terms":[{"offset":0,"value":"MG Road"},{"offset":9,"value":"National Highway 236"},{"offset":31,"value":"Maruti Housing Colony"},{"offset":54,"value":"Gurgaon"},{"offset":63,"value":"Haryana"},{"offset":72,"value":"India"}],"types":["transit_station","point_of_interest","establishment","geocode"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

I'm unable to understand the scenario that why place api are not working for Android-Key. Please anyone try to explain me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the Javascript library or Android?.... Your server key works because that's for web. SHA-1 fingerprint and keystores are for signing your apk, **not** for putting into a url.

Comment: I am using in Android. For android key i put sha-1 & package name in google api console not in url. In url i am putting the key which is returned from api console.

Comment: Okay, you still wouldn't put your android key into the url. The Android key is for Android applications. You would put it in the manifest file of your project. For Google maps v3 (javascript), you would either use a browser key or server key. You _can_ use the v3 within an Android application, since you can do still do stuff like make http requests and load things in webviews. Just note that they're for supposed to be for different platforms. From what I can tell from your question, there's nothing Android related necessary.

Comment: @Andy I have tried api sample also https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete 
Created Android Api for this sample and put that in manifest but it is also saying that invalid api. Should SHA-1 be from release keystore or having SHA-1 from debug keystore is also fine?

Comment: Can you include the actual error? If it's for Android Places, error codes are [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlacesStatusCodes#constant-summary). Either debug or release is fine, it won't affect it from working, unless you're trying to do an update. When publishing you'll want to use a release key.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to change existing Android key options or create a new key without package name and fingerprint restriction. If it will work, then you are probably have error in you package name ( .debug suffix is added automatically to package name in debug build )

Also make sure you've added your Android key in your manifest

Comment: i tried to make android key without package name and fingerprint and fortunately it works fine. But as you mention here that .debug suffix added automatically so i tried to add package with .debug suffix but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Check what is the name of the package when you are doing debug build, and also make sure that you grab SHA1 of the correct key

Answer (score 0):

For google places api while hitting api it required server key. Create server key with your sha1 fingerprint and use that key for google places api. And in manifest use api key there. Dont get confused api key and server key.

[image]

use android key in manifest and server key for places api. Afetr creating SERVER key wait for 5 minutes. Then your server key will be enabled

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE+TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE+OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&types=(cities)");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

here you have to use API_KEY is SERVER key NOT ANDROID key